# What is the symmetry associated with electric charge conservation

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, conservation-laws, charge, noethers-theorem

Is there a kind of symmetry that yields the conservation of charges?
and if so , how it works for both type of charges?

Electrical Charges

Comment: There many types of charges, so it is not clear when you write "both types of charges". Either way, (most) charges are conserved due to symmetries of the action; see Noether's theorem.

Comment: @Hunter, the two types referred to are positive and negative electrical charges, I presume.

Comment: @innisfree I would have assumed the OP refers to electric and magnetic charges, so it is not really clear.

Comment: @Hunter I was talking about Electrical charges.I edited the question.